# why can't I see the content in .ipynb?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have an .ipynb file, it should have content in it, because the file size is 576 kb.

[web snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RpbR.png)

However, when I open it using jupyter notebook, it is blank

[the file is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZIwe.png)

how could I solve this problem? it seems only this file encounters the problem, other notebooks are fine.

I want to open the file and see the content in the file.

Answer (score 1):

It is only `576 B`, 1000 times smaller than `576 kB`. Therefore the only file contents are some initial metadata and there really isn't anything in the file.